# Decode pending transaction input into map

Tags: go-ethereum, pending-transactions, golang

I'm attempting to decode a transaction input into a map, the input contains uint256 which are translated to bigint but the output value I get is incorrect.

I use this function to decode the input data bytes to interface

```go
func decodeTxParams(abi abi.ABI, v map[string]interface{}, data []byte) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    m, ok := abi.Methods["attack"]
    if !ok {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("error finding method")
    }

    if err := m.Inputs.UnpackIntoMap(v, data[4:]); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return v, nil
}
```

Using this sample input data, it appears that the converted value is wrong. Is there a way to convert this value to the original value?

```go
inputData := []byte("0xe1fa763800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0d77000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000121a")

v := make(map[string]interface{})
v, err = decodeTxParams(contractAbi, v, inputData)
if err != nil {
    return err
}


fmt.Println("Team id:", v["attackTeamId"].(*big.Int))
```

Outputs:

```
Team id: 21796157974083048550319244236929488537086114760591164995662604048548353814576
```

Expected output:

```
Team id: 4634
```

Comment: Since the output value is `3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030`. I'd suspect you need to convert the string from hexa to raw bytes. The `0` character is byte `30` in the ascii table.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, My output value isn't `30303030303...`. I also tried converting my output value to string using https://onlinestringtools.com/convert-ascii-to-string and it doesn't work so I don't think it's ascii.

Comment: If you convert `21796157974083048550319244236929488537086114760591164995662604048548353814576` as an integer to hexadecimal it returns `3030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030303030`.

Comment: converting that hexadecimal to string returns `00000000000000000000000000000000` which is incorrect as the expected output is `4634`

Comment: The input data is wrong so you are decoding garbage. I think you have to do something like `inputData, _  = hex.DecodeString("e1fa763800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000d0d77000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000121a")`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. You should post as an answer. Spent a lot of time researching this and didn't find a template for decoding transaction input data.

Comment: It will be better if you answer it I'm not a go developer and know what to write.